# How to maintain command after exiting SSH?

Tags: node.js, angular, ssh, cpanel, putty

I am using PuTTy to run a node.js server on a shared host (cPanel). My question is whether it is possible to maintain a command even after I completely close PuTTy? My issue is that when I for example type 'nohup node server.js &' and my server runs successfully, the moment I close down PuTTy, my node server goes down again. I would love it if there was a way to continously have my node server running even after exiting PuTTy completely or even shutting down my computer.

I have tried the following things:
- nohup (as seen above), however that does not maintain the connection after I close down PuTTy.
- forever.js however still same issue as nohup.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, my issue is not that I want the process to run in the background. My issue is whether it is possible to run the process even while my computer is shut down. It seems weird that I have to keep my PC on in order for the server process to continue, even though I'm using hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue was with cPanel, as it did not support node.js. I moved to DigitalOcean and it worked fantastically there.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for `nohup` or `disown` if  need to run a process that won’t be terminated after closing the terminal:

```
$ nohup your command &
$ exit
```

Or using `disown`:

```
$ your command &
$ disown
$ exit
```

If you have multiple commands:

```
$ sleep 3600 &
$ sleep 86400 &
```

By typing jobs something like this appears:

```
[1]  - running    sleep 3600
[2]  + running    sleep 86400
```

To disown let’s say only job 2:

```
$ disown %2
```

If your process is already running, you can pause it `ctrl+z`, something like this will appear:

```
$ sleep 3600
^Z
zsh: suspended  sleep 3600
```

Then type bg to put it in background:

```
$ bg
[1]  + continued  sleep 3600
```

After that you can disown and exit:

```
$ disown
$ exit
```

Comment: Hi there, as I mentioned in my post, I have tried nohup. The moment I shut down my pc, my node server also stops running. Same happens with disown.

Comment: @SquishyAura probably then you may want to use a supervisor, for example https://immortal.run/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to keep the command running in background even if you close the putty terminal.

- Very simple one is that you put "&" at the end of command like following

  node server.js &
- Second method is to use pm2. This is very efficient way to run the NodeJS server. It not only maintain session after closing terminal, but also if your operating system restarts, then it will automatically start the server again without user interaction to run the command.

  You can install pm2 by following command

  npm install pm2 -g

  And then start the node server as

  pm2 start server.js

Please update if this worked for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I have tried adding the '&' at the end, however my issue is not that I want the process to run in the background. My issue is whether it is possible to run the process even while my computer is shut down. It seems weird that I have to keep my PC on in order for the server process to continue, even though I'm using hosting.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to run the command on remote server. And you are running the command from your local system through putty. 
So, when you will  run the command using pm2, then process will keep running even if you will close the putty and shutdown your local system.

Comment: Ah, alright, I will try pm2 and update you later. Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Hi again, I just installed pm2 and ran it with the 'pm2 start server.js', but the issue still persists. When I close the SSH (PuTTy) in order to close my pc, the node servers also stops running. Any idea how I can fix this? Remember, I want an option where the node server still is run on the shared host EVEN after I close down the SSH and my pc.

Comment: Do you have an option to connect to server via screen provided by hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) if it is available on the server.