# How do I keep a Python application running in an EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ssh, terminal

I have a python application which I uploaded to an EC2 instance as a file named "example.py". I want this code to be running continuously, as it has a while loop that calls a 3rd party Twitter API every minute. If I run "python3 example.py", and close the terminal, the SSH session terminates. Will the python application continue running in that EC2 instance? How can I make that sure? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51398353/13317

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick Solution** - You run in SSH terminal:

```
nohup python3 example.py &
```

(best if you don't wanna see what is going on later)

or

**Best Solution** - You create a Screen in SSH terminal:

```
screen
```

Then you press ctrl+a+d to detach from it. Then you can close SSH safely. If you want to see what is going on later, you can just:

```
screen -r
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know this one. Here is a document link for others: https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=115540034

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) command to *disconnect from the current session* and `&` to run in background:

```
nohup python3 example.py &
```